# Rust: Is it possible to update a shared array with Rayon?

Tags: rust, rayon

I've got an array of `u8` which I will be partitioning in a complicated way.

Is it possible to update it from multiple rayon tasks? Sort of like this:

```rust
    let mut pixels = vec![0; w * h];

 
    rayon::scope(|s| {

        s.spawn(move |_s| {
            my_fn(&mut pixels);
        }
    }
```

BTW, I know about `into_par_iter`, but I can't partition the pixels ahead of time.

I.e. the partitioning scheme will be recursive and will depend on the outcome of some of the tasks.

FYI, I will be passing metadata about the pixels back and forth, which will influence which part of `pixels` `my_fn` will be working on, which is not shown here.

I'm getting this error, which prevents me from borrowing `pixels` afterwards.

```
    |                                 ------ variable moved due to use in closure
...
999 |             write_image(&pixels)
    |                                   ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Should I just give up on this design, or is there some way to make it work?

Comment: "the partitioning scheme will be recursive and will depend on the outcome of some of the tasks." Please explain more about this, especially how you know that no collisions can occur.

Comment: You can use atomics.

Comment: "the partitioning scheme will be recursive and will depend on the outcome of some of the tasks." Some of the regions will exit early because I can take advantage of a mathematical property, but I can't know which regions will have this property a-priori.  This is why I'm not just striping or tiling the pixels a head of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of atomics. If you never modify the same element from different threads, you can safely use [`Ordering::Relaxed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html#variant.Relaxed) (I think this is free? I am not an expert on that topic).

If you are unable to change the `Vec` creation, you can convert `&mut [int]` to `&mut [Atomic]` as they are guaranteed to have the same layout. On nightly, you can use [`from_mut_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI32.html#method.from_mut_slice). On stable, you can create it with little unsafe code:

```rust
fn from_mut_slice(v: &mut [i32]) -> &mut [AtomicI32] {
    unsafe { &mut *(v as *mut [i32] as *mut [AtomicI32]) }
}
```

If you want to avoid even that cost (and assuming there is a cost), you can use [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) if you never access the same pixel from different threads (but the burden to prove that is on you, as a user of unsafe code). Note that `UnsafeCell` is not `Sync` so you need to wrap it with a custom type implementing `Sync`; on nightly, you can use [`SyncUnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.SyncUnsafeCell.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I tried `UsafeCell` and so far I can't get it to work.  I always end up either being told that it's been moved or that two closures require access to pixels at the same time. (Rayon relies on two nested closures, which seems to complicate things.) I'm not sure how to make use of it in my scenario.  When would be the appropriate time to call `get()` on it?

Comment: @pnadeau On each thread, for each pixel. Don't have a big `UnsafeCell`; have one for each pixel.

Comment: I ended up using unsafe code and sharing the pixel array like this: `pixels: &SyncUnsafeCell<&mut [Option<Pixel>]>`  and when I need access to the pixels is use this idiom `pixels.get()`